# Flutter wakelock package not allowing the app to go into sleep mode

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, wakelock

I am building an application with the latest version of Flutter. I have been testing with a real  iOS device and whenever I am in the app my physical device does not go into sleep mode from inactivity. I have the settings on the physical device set to sleep within 30 seconds. I have tried using this package from pub.dev (https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock), but my app still stays on no matter what. The code is relatively simple such as:

```dart
await Wakelock.disable();
print(await Wakelock.enabled);
// returns false (device should allow sleep mode)
```

I would have thought that I didn't even need a package and that the default would allow the device to enter sleep mode. Has anyone encountered this and have a fix?

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of the [wakelock package](https://github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/wakelock).

As this kind of problem should generally be a GitHub issue instead of a StackOverflow question, I will write an answer for this instead of a short comment :)

---

#### Should the device go to sleep normally?

Yes, it should. And it does normally go to sleep.

I see two options here:

- either you have something setup incorrectly on your device or have some other service running.
- you are calling `Wakelock.enable` at some point after you have disabled it, which causes your device to not go to sleep.

#### How to solve the issue

I cannot tell you exactly what is happening because it should not from your description.

What you can do is the following: test an app that does not use `wakelock` at all and see if it goes to sleep. If yes, you can then try to see where you are calling `Wakelock.enable` and debug that to make sure that it is not being called at all.

---

After that, if you have more information, please [open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/wakelock/issues). Please make sure that you can get your device to go to sleep when having another app open before that.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing similar behaviour when running my Flutter app in debug mode on a physical iPhone.

However, if I run in release mode (--release), the device goes to sleep when it should do.

I am using WakelockPlus to enable/disable sleep and this is working as it should too.